# Backbone.js - delete bad request 400 (bad request)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, bad-request, http-delete

I'm using rails 4 and backbone in my app. I created delete method with Backbone, but when I try to delete using it, I get this error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 400 (Bad Request)
```

My delete method:

```
  deleteBook: (ev) ->
    @model.destroy()
)
```

Events:

```
  events:
    "click .delete": "deleteBook"
```

Pressing on that error, it shows that model type is `text/html`. So I suppose I have to convert it to json?

If I do like this:

```
  deleteBook: (ev) ->
    @model.toJSON().destroy()
)
```

Update:

My destroy method in rails controller (if it matters):

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@book.destroy

redirect_to '/'
```

Update2:

My Backbone model:

```
  $(document).ready ->
    window.Book = Backbone.Model.extend(url: ->
      (if @id then "/books/" + @id else "/books")
       urlRoot: '/books/'
    )
```

Then nothing happens and I won't get any error. So I think I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: I think your problem is not in Backbone but in your server. When you use destroy in the model, it starts an ajax request to delete it persistently.

Comment: @Puigcerber If it's in server how could I fix it? I updated my question with my rails destroy method if it matters for this problem.

Comment: The URL that you set up in the model has to be the same you use in Rails. If for example you have in your book model `urlRoot: '/books/'` you need http://localhost:3000/books/[id] to point to your Ruby method.

Comment: @Puigcerber if I use rails method, it destroys without a problem. How can I point that way? Also I added `urlRoot: '/books/'`, instead of initializing url, so then it gives this error now:
`Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`

Comment: are you using MongoDB? @id may actually be an object, which would explain why the string concatenation fails

Comment: @MicahRoberson No I'm using Sqlite

Comment: I don't know much about Ruby but you can check this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: And I would remove the line `(if @id then "/books/" + @id else "/books")`.

Comment: If I remove that, then destroy method stops working..

Comment: `urlRoot: '/books/',
idAttribute: 'id',`

Comment: @Puigcerber thanks, this one works.

Answer (score 1):

Why in url locate [object%20Object]?

Check value of @id in this place:

```
(if @id then "/books/" + @id else "/books")
```

Value should be a number, but i think you have an object in @id

Comment: No I have a number. It seems what was wrong was that `urlRoot` was inside url function inside backbone model. I moved it out and it started destroying.

Comment: I do not really understand this syntax, but in Backbone for JS url function would look like this:
`windows.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function () {
    return (this.id) ? '/books/' + this.id : '/books'
  }
});`

Comment: It's the same. I'm using coffeescript, thats why I don't need all these paranthesis etc.

Comment: can you put in console @id?

Answer (score 1):

After been discussing in the comments I'm posting it as an answer so you can accept it to close the issue.

If you are using you Backbone model outside of a collection you have to define explicitly the URL. You can define as well the id attribute.

```
$(document).ready ->
  window.Book = Backbone.Model.extend(
    urlRoot: '/books/'
    idAttribute: 'id'
  )
```

When you call `destroy()` in that model Backbone will start an ajax request to delete permanently the model using an HTTP request `DELETE http://localhost:3000/books/:id`.

So you need to map that URL to your Ruby controller following this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Cheers.